# Search Box in python that connect to localhost db

Tags: python, mysql, sql, tkinter

Hi everyone I am developing a project for my school and in that same project I need to have a search box in python, I already have more or less the idea of ​​how it develops but it is giving some errors. Sorry for my bad english but it is not my first language.
here I leave my code.

```
import mysql.connector
from tkinter import *
con = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="",
    database="testing"
)
top = Tk()
top.title('Search form')
top.geometry("200x200")
cursor = con.cursor()
name_box = Entry()
name_box.pack(side = RIGHT, expand = True)


def search(tup):
    try:
        person_name = name_box.get()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `email`=%s",name.box.get())
        return (cursor.fetchone())
    


        self.button = Button(self.frame, text="Display text", command=search)
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is missing a vital part see at the end the last commandm so you can enter as many seaches as you like

you were on the right track, but as you can see, mysql needs somemore lines

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime
from mysql.connector.cursor import MySQLCursorPrepared
from tkinter import *

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
     host="localhost",
     user="root",
     passwd="password",
     database="testdb"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor(cursor_class=MySQLCursorPrepared)
top = Tk()
top.title('Search form')
top.geometry("200x200")
name_box = Entry()
name_box.pack(side = RIGHT, expand = True)

def get_name():
    global person_name
    person_name = name_box.get()
    try:
        sql1="SELECT `mytable`.`Name` FROM `testdb`.`mytable` WHERE Name = %s;"
        mycursor.execute(sql1,(person_name,))
        records = mycursor.fetchall()
        for x in records:
            print(x)
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))

person_name = ""
button = Button(top, text="Display text", command=get_name)
button.pack()


mainloop()
```